# Getting 200 response with empty body in postman and in my spring boot it is giving Fetching Admin_user location whenever i hit get request in postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzWlC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ednDZ.png)

Comment: Dumping 2 links in the body, with a large title trying to be a question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to properly ask a question.

Comment: This is empty array, meaning no records. This is not really empty body.